# Script on startup without update-rc.d

Tags: linux, debian, logon-scripts, update

I've a debian minimal installation, and I just want to start a custom script at startup.

1. I've a script at **/etc/init.d/myscript**,
2. I put a `chmod 700`, and create symlinks to `S20myscript` into :

   ```
   /etc/rc2.d
   /etc/rc3.d
   /etc/rc4.d
   /etc/rc5.d
   ```

But then, script is NOT launched at all on startup.

When I use this script with `update-rc.d` (or `insserv`...), it works.

I don't understand, am I forced to use this command?

(and no, I don't want to use `/etc/rc.local`).

Answer (score 2):

Try removing all symlinks in the `rc*.d` directories.

Then, try running:

```
update-rc.d -n myscript enable
```

Where `-n` means `not-really`

This will list what insserv is supposed to do : making the symlink *and* generating some `.depend.*` files

Have a look at the `init.d/.depend.boot`, `init.d/.depend.start` and `init.d/.depend.stop`: maybe you need to update those files as well ? If you decide to change them by hand (but what's wrong with `update-rc.d`?) be extra careful that further calls to `update-rc.d` are not going to mess with your edits...

See `man startpar` and `man insserv` in order to gain some knowledge about the usage of how these `.depend.*` files.

And my final advice is: use `update-rc.d` :)

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with adding it to /etc/rc.local? That is the easiest way:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.    
#
# By default this script does nothing.
```